# I want to remove an element of a multidimensional list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, tuples

Let's say I have a multidimensional list of tuples i.e.

```
[[], [('A', 'Alpha'), ('B', 'Beta')]
```

but the first list of that multidimensional list is not always filled with elements.

**How to remove i.e. the 'A' element, alongside with its partner 'Alpha'?**

I must also add that the tuples are dynamic, meaning that in the second array there might be tuples such as:

```
[[], [('A', 'Alpha'), ('B', 'Beta'), ('C', 'Cocoa', 'Ccocoa2')]
```

due to the API creating ResourceSet objects, which I compare and then get results.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What is your criteria for removal? How do you decide what tuple to remove?

Comment: @CoryKramer So, let's say I want 'A' to be removed, so I do variable_name.remove('A'), or use the .pop(), as long as I can get it to remove those, I am fine with how its done.

Comment: @Jeni that would solve my problem, but as I said, the tuples are generated dynamically, with let's say new indexed being added of different sizes, and I cannot see which index nor what they have in them, unless I look up in the code - that is what I want to avoid, I have the first names of tuples, but the rest is dynamic.

Comment: `[[i for i in sub if i[0] != 'A'] for sub in data]` if your original list of lists was called `data`

Comment: @CoryKramer works perfectly! Let's say now that there is a value added to both lists ('blablabla', 'blablabla', 'blablabla'), how do I extract that data so I can use it based on the name? Thanks!